# Check whether an array is a subset of another

Tags: c#, list, linq, subset

Any idea on how to check whether that list is a subset of another?

Specifically, I have

```
List<double> t1 = new List<double> { 1, 3, 5 };
List<double> t2 = new List<double> { 1, 5 };
```

How to check that t2 is a subset of t1, using LINQ?

Comment: If the lists are sorted (as in your example), this should be possible in O(n+m) time.

Answer (score 284, accepted):

```
bool isSubset = !t2.Except(t1).Any();
```

Comment: I've created extension method http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2011/05/13/issubsetof-list-extension.aspx

Comment: @Bul Ikana Working of this code is simple, extension method internally calls the Equals and GetHashCode of the overridden object class methods if there's no IEqualityComparer provided for the job.

Comment: If the lists are length n and m, what's the time complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: Would be nice if this was boiled down to a linq method called ContainsAll

Comment: I wonder if an intersection would be faster - `t1.Intersect(t2).Count() == t2.Count()`

Answer (score 71):

Use HashSet instead of List if working with sets.  Then you can simply use [IsSubsetOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358446.aspx)

```
HashSet<double> t1 = new HashSet<double>{1,3,5};
HashSet<double> t2 = new HashSet<double>{1,5};

bool isSubset = t2.IsSubsetOf(t1);
```

Sorry that it doesn't use LINQ.  :-(

If you need to use lists, then @Jared's solution works with the caveat that you will need to remove any repeated elements that exist.

Comment: Exactly. You want a set operation, use the class designed for them. Cameron's solution is creative, but not as clear/expressive as the HashSet.

Comment: Um I disagree because the question specifically says "use LINQ".

Comment: @JaredPar: So what? Is it not better to show someone the right way than the way they want to go?

Comment: A list maintains its order but a set does not. If the order is important this would give incorrect results.

Answer (score 22):

This is a significantly more efficient solution than the others posted here, especially the top solution:

```
bool isSubset = t2.All(elem => t1.Contains(elem));
```

If you can find a single element in t2 that isn't in t1, then you know that t2 is not a subset of t1. The advantage of this method is that it is done all in-place, without allocating additional space, unlike the solutions using .Except or .Intersect. Furthermore, this solution is able to break as soon as it finds a single element that violates the subset condition, while the others continue searching. Below is the optimal long form of the solution, which is only marginally faster in my tests than the above shorthand solution.

```
bool isSubset = true;
foreach (var element in t2) {
    if (!t1.Contains(element)) {
        isSubset = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

I did some rudimentary performance analysis of all the solutions, and the results are drastic. These two solutions are about 100x faster than the .Except() and .Intersect() solutions, and use no additional memory.

Comment: That is exactly what `!t2.Except(t1).Any()` is doing. Linq is working back to forth. `Any()` is asking an `IEnumerable` if there is at least one element. In this scenario `t2.Except(t1)` is only emitting the first element of `t2` which is not in `t1`. If the first element of `t2` is not in `t1` it finishes fastest, if all elements of `t2` are in `t1` it runs the longest.

Comment: While playing around with some sort of benchmark, I found out, when you take `t1={1,2,3,...9999}` and `t2={9999,9998,99997...9000}`, you get the following measurements: `!t2.Except(t1).Any():    1ms -> t2.All(e => t1.Contains(e)):  702ms`. And it get's worse the bigger the range.

Comment: That is incorrect. t2.Except(t1) is a set subtraction operation, and returns ALL the remaining elements of t2 minus t1. It creates an entire new collection, and requires additional memory to do so. It is not emitting only the first element of t2 which is not in t1, it is emitting ALL elements of t2 that are not in t1. In order to return the set of ALL elements not in t1, it must traverse the entire set. For example, if t2={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} and t1={2,4,6,8}, then t2.Except(t1) returns {1,3,5,7}.

Comment: This is not the way Linq works. `t2.Except (t1)` is returning an `IEnumerable` not a `Collection`. It only emits all of the possible items if you iterate completely over it, for example by `ToArray ()` or `ToList ()` or use `foreach` without breaking inside. Search for *linq deferred execution* to read more about that concept.

Comment: From the documentation of `Except ()`: *This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For Each in Visual Basic.* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm fully aware of how deferred execution works in Linq. You can defer the execution all you want, but when you want to determine if t2 is a subset of t1, you'll need to iterate the entire list to figure it out. There is no getting around that fact.

Comment: Lets take the example from your comment `t2={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}` `t1={2,4,6,8}` `t2.Except(t1)` => first element of t2 = *1* => difference of *1* to t1 is *1* (checked against {2,4,6,8}) => `Except()` emits first element *1* => `Any()` gets an element => `Any()` results in true => no further check of elements in t2.

Comment: This is a good answer, but tarnished by the misconception outlined by @abto. I suggest an edit to focus on the actual technique independently of the alternatives.

Answer (score 13):

If you are **unit-testing** you can also utilize the [CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.issubsetof.aspx) method :

```
CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf(subset, superset);
```

In the above case this would mean:

```
CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf(t2, t1);
```

Answer (score 9):

I have spent some time benchmarking 3 working solutions in this answer with BenchmarkDotNet.

- `!t2.Except(t1).Any()` called Except().Any()
- `t2.IsSubsetOf(t1)` called HashSet
- `t2.All(elem => t1.Contains(elem))` called All(=>Contains)

I have varied 3 params:

- count of supersets
- length of subset
- variability in items

All supersets were random length and contained items in range `[0; Variability)`. Subsets had fixed length and contained items in range `[0; Variability)`.

The winner is All(=>Contains) method - it is sometimes up to 30x times faster than using HashSets and 50x faster than Except().Any().

Code can be found on [github](https://github.com/zetroot/SubsetAlgorithmsBenchmark)

**UPDATE**
As mentioned in comments by @Gert Arnold I had a bug in my benchmark. I called `ToHashSet()` inside every iteration.
So i build also a collection of prebuilt hashsets and added a pure-hashset test named `prebuilt HashSet`.
It is not an absolute winner and sometimes it looses `All(=>Contains)` algorithm. It seems to me the point is in variability (and duplicates) in supersets. When variability in values is low - hashset wins, as it removes it from data.

The final table goes here:

```
|             Method | SupersetsInIteration | SubsetLength | Variability |          Mean |        Error |       StdDev |        Median |
|------------------- |--------------------- |------------- |------------ |--------------:|-------------:|-------------:|--------------:|
|     Except().Any() |                 1000 |           10 |         100 |   1,485.89 μs |     7.363 μs |     6.887 μs |   1,488.36 μs |
|        ToHashSet() |                 1000 |           10 |         100 |   1,015.59 μs |     5.099 μs |     4.770 μs |   1,015.43 μs |
| prebuilt HashSet   |                 1000 |           10 |         100 |      38.76 μs |     0.065 μs |     0.054 μs |      38.78 μs |
|    All(=>Contains) |                 1000 |           10 |         100 |     105.46 μs |     0.320 μs |     0.267 μs |     105.38 μs |
|     Except().Any() |                 1000 |           10 |       10000 |   1,912.17 μs |    38.180 μs |    87.725 μs |   1,890.72 μs |
|        ToHashSet() |                 1000 |           10 |       10000 |   1,038.70 μs |    20.028 μs |    40.459 μs |   1,019.35 μs |
| prebuilt HashSet   |                 1000 |           10 |       10000 |      28.22 μs |     0.165 μs |     0.155 μs |      28.24 μs |
|    All(=>Contains) |                 1000 |           10 |       10000 |      81.47 μs |     0.117 μs |     0.109 μs |      81.45 μs |
|     Except().Any() |                 1000 |           50 |         100 |   4,888.22 μs |    81.268 μs |    76.019 μs |   4,854.42 μs |
|        ToHashSet() |                 1000 |           50 |         100 |   4,323.23 μs |    21.424 μs |    18.992 μs |   4,315.16 μs |
| prebuilt HashSet   |                 1000 |           50 |         100 |     186.53 μs |     1.257 μs |     1.176 μs |     186.35 μs |
|    All(=>Contains) |                 1000 |           50 |         100 |   1,173.37 μs |     2.667 μs |     2.227 μs |   1,173.08 μs |
|     Except().Any() |                 1000 |           50 |       10000 |   7,148.22 μs |    20.545 μs |    19.218 μs |   7,138.22 μs |
|        ToHashSet() |                 1000 |           50 |       10000 |   4,576.69 μs |    20.955 μs |    17.499 μs |   4,574.34 μs |
| prebuilt HashSet   |                 1000 |           50 |       10000 |      33.87 μs |     0.160 μs |     0.142 μs |      33.85 μs |
|    All(=>Contains) |                 1000 |           50 |       10000 |     131.34 μs |     0.569 μs |     0.475 μs |     131.24 μs |
|     Except().Any() |                10000 |           10 |         100 |  14,798.42 μs |   120.423 μs |   112.643 μs |  14,775.43 μs |
|        ToHashSet() |                10000 |           10 |         100 |  10,263.52 μs |    64.082 μs |    59.942 μs |  10,265.58 μs |
| prebuilt HashSet   |                10000 |           10 |         100 |   1,241.19 μs |     4.248 μs |     3.973 μs |   1,241.75 μs |
|    All(=>Contains) |                10000 |           10 |         100 |   1,058.41 μs |     6.766 μs |     6.329 μs |   1,059.22 μs |
|     Except().Any() |                10000 |           10 |       10000 |  16,318.65 μs |    97.878 μs |    91.555 μs |  16,310.02 μs |
|        ToHashSet() |                10000 |           10 |       10000 |  10,393.23 μs |    68.236 μs |    63.828 μs |  10,386.27 μs |
| prebuilt HashSet   |                10000 |           10 |       10000 |   1,087.21 μs |     2.812 μs |     2.631 μs |   1,085.89 μs |
|    All(=>Contains) |                10000 |           10 |       10000 |     847.88 μs |     1.536 μs |     1.436 μs |     847.34 μs |
|     Except().Any() |                10000 |           50 |         100 |  48,257.76 μs |   232.573 μs |   181.578 μs |  48,236.31 μs |
|        ToHashSet() |                10000 |           50 |         100 |  43,938.46 μs |   994.200 μs | 2,687.877 μs |  42,877.97 μs |
| prebuilt HashSet   |                10000 |           50 |         100 |   4,634.98 μs |    16.757 μs |    15.675 μs |   4,643.17 μs |
|    All(=>Contains) |                10000 |           50 |         100 |  10,256.62 μs |    26.440 μs |    24.732 μs |  10,243.34 μs |
|     Except().Any() |                10000 |           50 |       10000 |  73,192.15 μs |   479.584 μs |   425.139 μs |  73,077.26 μs |
|        ToHashSet() |                10000 |           50 |       10000 |  45,880.72 μs |   141.497 μs |   125.433 μs |  45,860.50 μs |
| prebuilt HashSet   |                10000 |           50 |       10000 |   1,620.61 μs |     3.507 μs |     3.280 μs |   1,620.52 μs |
|    All(=>Contains) |                10000 |           50 |       10000 |   1,460.01 μs |     1.819 μs |     1.702 μs |   1,459.49 μs |
|     Except().Any() |               100000 |           10 |         100 | 149,047.91 μs | 1,696.388 μs | 1,586.803 μs | 149,063.20 μs |
|        ToHashSet() |               100000 |           10 |         100 | 100,657.74 μs |   150.890 μs |   117.805 μs | 100,654.39 μs |
| prebuilt HashSet   |               100000 |           10 |         100 |  12,753.33 μs |    17.257 μs |    15.298 μs |  12,749.85 μs |
|    All(=>Contains) |               100000 |           10 |         100 |  11,238.79 μs |    54.228 μs |    50.725 μs |  11,247.03 μs |
|     Except().Any() |               100000 |           10 |       10000 | 163,277.55 μs | 1,096.107 μs | 1,025.299 μs | 163,556.98 μs |
|        ToHashSet() |               100000 |           10 |       10000 |  99,927.78 μs |   403.811 μs |   337.201 μs |  99,812.12 μs |
| prebuilt HashSet   |               100000 |           10 |       10000 |  11,671.99 μs |     6.753 μs |     5.986 μs |  11,672.28 μs |
|    All(=>Contains) |               100000 |           10 |       10000 |   8,217.51 μs |    67.959 μs |    56.749 μs |   8,225.85 μs |
|     Except().Any() |               100000 |           50 |         100 | 493,925.76 μs | 2,169.048 μs | 1,922.805 μs | 493,386.70 μs |
|        ToHashSet() |               100000 |           50 |         100 | 432,214.15 μs | 1,261.673 μs | 1,180.169 μs | 431,624.50 μs |
| prebuilt HashSet   |               100000 |           50 |         100 |  49,593.29 μs |    75.300 μs |    66.751 μs |  49,598.45 μs |
|    All(=>Contains) |               100000 |           50 |         100 |  98,662.71 μs |   119.057 μs |   111.366 μs |  98,656.00 μs |
|     Except().Any() |               100000 |           50 |       10000 | 733,526.81 μs | 8,728.516 μs | 8,164.659 μs | 733,455.20 μs |
|        ToHashSet() |               100000 |           50 |       10000 | 460,166.27 μs | 7,227.011 μs | 6,760.150 μs | 457,359.70 μs |
| prebuilt HashSet   |               100000 |           50 |       10000 |  17,443.96 μs |    10.839 μs |     9.608 μs |  17,443.40 μs |
|    All(=>Contains) |               100000 |           50 |       10000 |  14,222.31 μs |    47.090 μs |    44.048 μs |  14,217.94 μs |
```

Comment: The comparison isn't fair. You include `ToHashSet()` in the measured code. The results would be quite different if you'd create hashsets and compare only `IsSubsetOf`. No doubt `HashSet` will win easily.

Comment: Good point, thank you! I will rerun tests on prepared hashsets in global setup. I have included it into benchmark code as we do no usually use this specific data structure in common business code, but i will check it.

Answer (score 6):

@Cameron's solution as an extension method:

```
public static bool IsSubsetOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
{
    return !a.Except(b).Any();
}
```

Usage:

```
bool isSubset = t2.IsSubsetOf(t1);
```

(This is similar, but not quite the same as the one posted on @Michael's blog)

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answers from @Cameron and @Neil I wrote an extension method that uses the same terminology as the Enumerable class.

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines whether a sequence contains the specified elements by using the default equality comparer.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the elements of source.</typeparam>
/// <param name="source">A sequence in which to locate the values.</param>
/// <param name="values">The values to locate in the sequence.</param>
/// <returns>true if the source sequence contains elements that have the specified values; otherwise, false.</returns>
public static bool ContainsAll<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, IEnumerable<TSource> values)
{
    return !values.Except(source).Any();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given then we have 2 arrays, `array1` and `array2` and we want to check that all `array1` values exists in `array2`:

```
array1.All(ar1 => array2.Any(ar2 => ar2.Equals(ar1)));
```

Note: `ar2.Equals(ar1)` can be replaced if equality is described in other way.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
static bool IsSubSet<A>(A[] set, A[] toCheck) {
  return set.Length == (toCheck.Intersect(set)).Count();
}
```

The idea here is that Intersect will only return the values that are in both Arrays.  At this point if the length of the resulting set is the same as the original set, then all elements in "set" are also in "check" and therefore "set" is a subset of "toCheck"

Note: My solution does not work if "set" has duplicates.  I'm not changing it because I don't want to steal other people's votes.

Hint: I voted for Cameron's answer.

Comment: This works if they are indeed sets, but not if the second "set" contains repeated elements since it is really a list.  You may want to use HashSet<double> to ensure that it has set semantics.

Comment: doesn't work when both Arrays have elements, which are not in the other Array.

Answer (score -1):

> Here we check that if there is any element present in the child list(i.e `t2`) which is not contained by the parent list(i.e `t1`).If none such exists then the list is subset of the other

eg:

```
bool isSubset = !(t2.Any(x => !t1.Contains(x)));
```

Comment: `not Any not` is the same as plain `All`.