# Does .NET have a way to check if List a contains all items in List b?

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, mono

I have the following method:

```
namespace ListHelper
{
    public class ListHelper<T>
    {
        public static bool ContainsAllItems(List<T> a, List<T> b)
        {
            return b.TrueForAll(delegate(T t)
            {
                return a.Contains(t);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of which is to determine if a List contains all the elements of another list. It would appear to me that something like this would be built into .NET already, is that the case and am I duplicating functionality?

Edit: My apologies for not stating up front that I'm using this code on Mono version 2.4.2.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another

Comment: Your algorithm is quadratic O(nm). If the lists are sorted, testing if one is a subset of another should be possible in O(n+m) time.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5, it's easy:

```
public class ListHelper<T>
{
    public static bool ContainsAllItems(List<T> a, List<T> b)
    {
        return !b.Except(a).Any();
    }
}
```

This checks whether there are any elements in `b` which aren't in `a` - and then inverts the result.

Note that it would be slightly more conventional to make the *method* generic rather than the class, and there's no reason to require `List<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` - so this would probably be preferred:

```
public static class LinqExtras // Or whatever
{
    public static bool ContainsAllItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
    {
        return !b.Except(a).Any();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is untested, but wouldn't 
 return b.Except(a).Empty();
be much more readable ?

Comment: Except that Empty() doesn't return a boolean. It returns an IEnumerable<T> with no items.

Comment: This requires Linq right? If so, I don't think that's available in Mono, which is what I'm using at the moment.

Comment: You can use LINQ to Objects in Mono, I believe... but it would be helpful if you'd state the requirements in the question to start with. Which version of Mono are you using?

Comment: I've just checked the sources for Mono 2.4.2.3, and it definitely includes LINQ to Objects.

Comment: If the lists are length n and m, what's the time complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: @ColonelPanic: Assuming no hash collisions, O(n+m).

Comment: If two lists are identical, this will return false, because there wouldn't be Any() elements found after the Except()

Comment: @Bojan: No, it will return true, because the expression starts with `!`. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/QdXPy7 for a runnable example.

Answer (score 49):

Included in .NET 4:  [Enumerable.All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static bool ContainsAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> values)
{
    return values.All(value => source.Contains(value));
}
```

Comment: `Enumerable.All` existed before .Net 4.0, and here it's a O(N^2) operation [as opposed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520642/does-net-have-a-way-to-check-if-list-a-contains-all-items-in-list-b#comment56979445_1520664) the one in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520664/11683).

Answer (score 36):

Just for fun, @JonSkeet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520664/1037948) as an extension method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Does a list contain all values of another list?
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Needs .NET 3.5 or greater.  Source:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520664/1037948 </remarks>
/// <typeparam name="T">list value type</typeparam>
/// <param name="containingList">the larger list we're checking in</param>
/// <param name="lookupList">the list to look for in the containing list</param>
/// <returns>true if it has everything</returns>
public static bool ContainsAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> containingList, IEnumerable<T> lookupList) {
    return ! lookupList.Except(containingList).Any();
}
```

Comment: similarly:  Contains Any = `public static bool ContainsAny<T>(this IEnumerable<T> haystack, IEnumerable<T> needle) { return haystack.Intersect(needle).Count() > 0; }`.  I tried some quick performance comparisons to `haystack.Count() - 1 >= haystack.Except(needle).Count();` and `Intersect` seemed to do better most of the time.

Comment: sheesh...use `Any()` not `Count() > 0`:  `public static bool ContainsAny<T>(this IEnumerable<T> haystack, IEnumerable<T> needle) { return haystack.Intersect(needle).Any(); }`

Answer (score 3):

I know a way using LinQ methods. It's a bit weird to read, but works pretty well

```
var motherList = new List<string> { "Hello", "World", "User };
var sonList = new List<string> { "Hello", "User" };
```

You want to check if sonList is totally in motherList

To do so:

```
sonList.All(str => moterList.Any(word => word == str));

// Reading literally, would be like "For each of all items 
// in sonList, test if it's in motherList
```

Please check it on and see if works there too. Hope it helps ;-)

Comment: This works. But please correct the typo in this line:
`bool result = sonList.All(str => motherList.Any(word => word == str));`

Answer (score -1):

You could also use another way. Override equals and use this

```
public bool ContainsAll(List<T> a,List<T> check)
{
   list l = new List<T>(check);
   foreach(T _t in a)
   {
      if(check.Contains(t))
      {
         check.Remove(t);
         if(check.Count == 0)
         {
            return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: `list l = new List<T>(check);` I dont think this would compile and if it does, its totally unecessary as `check` is already a list

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static bool ContainsAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> containingList, IEnumerable<T> lookupList)
    {
        return containingList.Intersect(lookupList).Count() == lookupList.Count();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?