# Check if all elements in List1<T> are in List2<T> C#

Tags: c#, list

Is it possible to Know or check if all elements in List1 is a part of List2 ?
Example if I have

```
List1 = { 1,2,3,4 }

List2 = { 1,2,3,5,6,4 }
```

I want to get True if all elements in List 1 are in List 2 and False otherwise

> Note : Without ForLoop

List may be list of integers , string ,...etc

Comment: How do you expect to check all elements in a list without a for loop... Using LINQ, or some equivalent trickery still boils down to enumerating each element... so basically a for loop!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does .NET have a way to check if List a contains all items in List b?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520642/does-net-have-a-way-to-check-if-list-a-contains-all-items-in-list-b)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

bool allInList2 = !List1.Except(List2).Any();
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) method.

Then if the result is the same length as `List1` you know that all its elements are contained in `List2`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [HashSet.IsProperSubsetOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351418.aspx) (or [IsProperSupersetOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299734.aspx)) method like so:

```
var hashset1 = new HashSet<int>(list1);
if (hashset1.IsProperSubsetOf(list2)) ...
```

Answer (score 5):

### Best performance LINQ solution

This code sample
- checks whether there are **any elements in *b* which aren't in *a***
- and then **inverts the result**.

```
using System.Linq;
....
public static bool ContainsAllItems(List<T> a, List<T> b)
{
    return !b.Except(a).Any();
}
```

Originally found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520664/497040).

Answer (score 4):

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4 };

list1.All(x => list2.Contains(x));
```

Comment: Perfect, but i think you mistyped list1 on the lambda, you have to change it for list2: list1.All(x => list2.Contains(x));

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) LINQ method:

```
List1.Intersect(List2).Count() == List1.Count()
```

Note that this does boil down to iterating over both lists - no way around that!

Answer (score 2):

create an [intersection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) of these lists and query that intersection result list only.
of course, internally there is a loop (and must be ob any given solution)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
bool value = !(l1.Any(item => !l2.Contains(item)));
```

Comment: He doesn't want `value`, but `!value` as the result ;)

Comment: Haris ur solution will return true if any member of list1 is present in list2 or am i missing something?

Comment: Little hint to simplify your overly complex expression: `!list.Any(x => condition) == list.All(x => !condition)`

Answer (score 0):

Extension method, long version:

```
public static IsSubetOf (this IEnumerable coll1, IEnumerable coll2)
{
  foreach (var elem in coll1)
  {
    if (!coll2.Contains (elem))
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Short version:

```
public static IsSubetOf (this IEnumerable<T> coll1, IEnumerable<T> coll2)
{
  return !coll1.Any (x => !coll2.Contains (x));
}
```