# How can I know if ListA has everything ListB has?

Tags: c#

If I have the following...

```
List<string> listA = new List<string>();
listA.Add("a");
listA.Add("b");
listA.Add("c");
listA.Add("d");

List<string> listB = new List<string>();
listB.Add("b");
listB.Add("d");
```

How can I know if listA has everything listB has?

Comment: Asked several times. Please do some research. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520642/does-net-have-a-way-to-check-if-list-a-contains-all-items-in-list-b

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)

```
bool allBinA = !listB.Except(listA).Any();
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/ZtNcDi)

Answer (score 2):

you could do it the raw (slow) way to make sure

```
bool contains_all = true;

foreach(String s in listA) {
  if(!listB.Contains(s)) {
    contains_all = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

although this does perform an exhaustive search on every element within the array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bool result = listB.Intersect(listA).Count() == listB.Count;
```

And also this:

```
bool result2 = listB.Select(input => !listA.Contains(input)).Count() > 0;
```

Comment: What if list A has more than list B?

Answer (score 0):

```
bool result = false;

if (listB.Count>listA.Count) result =  listB.Intersect(listA).Count() == listB.Count;

else result =  listA.Intersect(listB).Count() == listA.Count;
```