# Check if one list contains all items from another list in order

Tags: c#, linq, list

How can I determine if List A contains all of the elements from List B in the same order?

List A can have additional elements that List B does not have, but must contain all elements of List B in the order that List B has them.

---

**Example 1** (*List A* ending with *..., **4, 0,** 6*):

```
List A:    List B:
5          2
9          3
2          4
3
4
0
6
```

This should return **True**.

---

**Example 2** (*List A* ending with *..., **0, 4**, 6*):

```
List A:    List B:
5          2
9          3
2          4
3
0
4
6
```

This should return **False**.

---

I found this [answer from JonSkeet to see if List A contains all elements from List B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520642/does-net-have-a-way-to-check-if-list-a-contains-all-items-in-list-b) however, that does not require them to be in the same order.

Comment: Not only the order doesn't matter in J.Skeets answer but also the count. So `{1,2,2,3}` and `{1,2,3}`  would return `true` with `Enumerable.Except` since it is a set method which eliminates duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick way:

```
var equal = listA.Count - listB.Count < 0 
    ? false 
    : Enumerable.Range(0, listA.Count - listB.Count).Any(i => 
      listA.Skip(i).Take(listB.Count).SequenceEqual(listB));
```

---

However, I'd prefer to use an extension method like this:

```
public static bool ContainsSequence<T>(this IEnumerable<T> outer, 
                                       IEnumerable<T> inner)
{
    var innerCount = inner.Count();
    for(int i = 0; i < outer.Count() - innerCount; i++)
    {
        if(outer.Skip(i).Take(innerCount).SequenceEqual(inner))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
 }
```

which you can call like:

```
var equals = listA.ContainsSequence(listB);
```

---

And here's a more *efficient* version of the same extension method specific to `List<T>`:

```
public static bool ContainsSequence<T>(this List<T> outer, List<T> inner)
{
    var innerCount = inner.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < outer.Count - innerCount; i++)
    {
        bool isMatch = true;
        for (int x = 0; x < innerCount; x++)
        {
            if (!outer[i + x].Equals(inner[x]))
            {
                isMatch = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isMatch) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Does not work if duplicates should matter,Intersect eliminates duplicates.

Comment: @TimSchmelter added a solution for duplicates as well.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Your's is slightly faster than Tim's.

Comment: @Ricketts Thank you. But normally, the last method I provided should be faster. Your test data is a bit biased since the match is always at the beginning. For example, add another set of "B"s before "A"s in ListA, and you should find my List<T> specific method is faster.

Answer (score 4):

This takes each part of `ListA` and compares it with `ListB` with [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx):

```
bool containsSameSequence = ListA
    .Where((item, index) => index <= ListA.Count - ListB.Count)
    .Select((item, index) => ListA.Skip(index).Take(ListB.Count))
    .Any(part => part.SequenceEqual(ListB));
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/KkiTTu)

It  returns `true` on the first matching sequence.

Comment: Both your's and Eren's solutions work. However, Eren's seems to be slightly faster (and easier to read), demo using strings here: http://ideone.com/zywMpv

Comment: @Ricketts: No problem. However, the sample data is not very meaningful since you are generating the same sequence for both lists(`ListA` has just more elements), so the first test will always succeed. Since both approaches are actually the same with different syntax i assume that both will have similar performance.

Comment: @Ricketts: Also, you have not used my code with the `Where` which is the Linq version of Eren's shortened `for`-loop. That's the reason for the performance difference.

Comment: You are correct about my tests, check the updated version: http://ideone.com/zywMpv

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.Join()` to concat ListA elements together. Then use it again to concat ListB elements together. Then use `ConcatListA.IndexOf(ConcatListB)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think my version is more efficient.

```
public static class CollectionExtension
{
    public static bool SequenceContain<T>(this IEnumerable<T> target, IEnumerable<T> that)
    {
        var targetEnumerater = target.GetEnumerator();
        var thatEnumerater = that.GetEnumerator();
        var thatHasValue = thatEnumerater.MoveNext();
        var targetHasValue = targetEnumerater.MoveNext();
        var matchCount = 0;
        try
        {
            while (thatHasValue && targetHasValue)
            {
                if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(targetEnumerater.Current, thatEnumerater.Current))
                {
                    if (matchCount > 0)
                    {
                        thatEnumerater.Reset();
                        thatEnumerater.MoveNext();
                        matchCount = 0;
                    }
                    targetHasValue = targetEnumerater.MoveNext();
                    continue;
                }
                targetHasValue = targetEnumerater.MoveNext();
                thatHasValue = thatEnumerater.MoveNext();
                matchCount++;
            }
            return matchCount == that.Count();
        }
        finally
        {
            thatEnumerater.Dispose();
            targetEnumerater.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```