# How to check if list contains another list in same order

Tags: c#, list

Is there any simple way in c# to check if list consist of another list?.
Here is example, 
I have:

`var list1 = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,};`
and second one 
`var list2 = new List<int>() {5, 6};`

this list is a part of first list so it should return true.

`var list1 = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,};` 
and 
`var list3 = new List<int>() {1, 3};` should return false.

It's not about checking if all elements in first list exist in second list but also about order. It has to have the same order.

Comment: Do you want a general solution or for integer lists only?

Comment: What have you tried? What code have you written? What research have you performed?

Comment: Do you mean contains another list in same order?

Comment: I would have been good if your question contained valid code to work from.

Comment: Yes for now i need it just for intigers. For now i was trying to find if already there is any existing solution for this problem. And yes order is important

Comment: _"For now i was trying to find if already there is any existing solution for this problem"_ - but "C# find list in list" (or "C# test collection contains sequence") yields thousands of web search results. What have you tried?

Comment: See [Check if one list contains all items from another list in order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037625/check-if-one-list-contains-all-items-from-another-list-in-order).

Comment: @dotctor - The `,` at the end of each of my lists in my answer were intended. I have rolled-back your edit.

Comment: What is the purpose? @Enigmativity

Comment: @dotctor - It's valid syntax and it aids in refactoring.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public bool ContainsSubsequence<T>(List<T> sequence, List<T> subsequence)
{
    return
        Enumerable
            .Range(0, sequence.Count - subsequence.Count + 1)
            .Any(n => sequence.Skip(n).Take(subsequence.Count).SequenceEqual(subsequence));
}
```

This code uses `Enumerable.Range` to run through every possible starting point within `sequence` that could be the same as `subsequence`, and checks if the segment of `sequence` the same size as `subsequence` at this position is actually equal to `subsequence`.

So for this code:

```
var list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, };
var list2 = new List<int>() { 5, 6, };
var list3 = new List<int>() { 1, 3, };

Console.WriteLine(ContainsSubsequence(list1, list2));
Console.WriteLine(ContainsSubsequence(list1, list3));
```

I get:

```
True
False
```

Comment: With `var list3 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, };` it should returns `true` but it returns `false`!

Comment: @user2946329 - I did have an error in the code, but I fixed it. `{ 1, 2 }` works fine now.

Comment: @Enigmativity .. Yes. Now it became a good and comprehensive solution. +1.

Comment: I tested this a litle bit and it throws an exception if sequence.Count is less than subsequence.Count. So it's quite necessary to add "if" condition at the begining of this method.

Comment: @wgrzesiak147 - Yes, that's fair enough. I wrote the code for brevity, not robustness. I generally assume that it's easy to see the intent of the code if it is kept as simple as possible. But I do believe the most coders would understand the need to fortify the code.

Comment: I have no idea what the code means, but it works, and looks like magic. so i like it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @GeorgeVovos & @Enigmativity for pointing out the issues in first solution.

```
public static bool HasSubSequence(List<int> main, List<int> query)
{
    var startIndex = main.IndexOf(query.First());
    if (main == null || query == null || startIndex < 0)
        return false;

    while (startIndex >= 0)
    {        
        if (main.Count - startIndex < query.Count)
            return false;
        var nonMatch = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < query.Count; i++)
        {
            if (main[i + startIndex] != query[i])
            {
                main = main.Skip(startIndex + 1).ToList();
                startIndex = main.IndexOf(query.First());
                nonMatch = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!nonMatch)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Example

```
var l1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var l2 = new List<int> { 4, 5 };
var l3 = new List<int> { 1, 3 };
var l4 = new List<int> { 5, 6 };

var l5 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 2, 4, 8 };
var l6 = new List<int> { 2, 4 };

var test1 = HasSubSequence(l1, l2); //true
var test2 = HasSubSequence(l1, l3); //false
var test3 = HasSubSequence(l1, l4); //false

var test5 = HasSubSequence(l5, l6); //true
```

Comment: Order of the elements is important.

Comment: You need to wrap your code with a while loop (and modify indexof a little) because the first element of the second list might exists before

Comment: This still doesn't work if `query.First()` appears in `main` before the subsequence.

Comment: Indeed,the for loop has to change also.the list my not appear at the start