# Function to linq conversion

Tags: c#, linq

I have a function which I believe can be simplified into LINQ but have been unable to do so yet.
The function looks like this:

```
private IList<Colour> GetDifference(IList<Colour> firstList, IList<Colour> secondList)
{

    // Create a new list
    var list = new List<Colour>();

    // Loop through the first list
    foreach (var first in firstList)
    {

        // Create a boolean and set to false
        var found = false;

        // Loop through the second list
        foreach (var second in secondList)
        {

            // If the first item id is the same as the second item id
            if (first.Id == second.Id)
            {

                // Mark it has being found
                found = true;
            }
        }

        // After we have looped through the second list, if we haven't found a match
        if (!found)
        {

            // Add the item to our list
            list.Add(first);
        }
    }

    // Return our differences
    return list;
}
```

Can this be converted to a LINQ expression easily?

Comment: You may find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520642/does-net-have-a-way-to-check-if-list-a-contains-all-items-in-list-b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is `Colour`?  If it overrides `Equals` to compare by `Id` then this would work:

```
firstList.Except(secondList);
```

If `Colour` does not override `Equals` or it would be wrong for you to do so in the wider context, you could implement an `IEqualityComparer<Colour>` and pass this as a parameter:

```
firstList.Except(secondList, comparer);
```

See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb336390(v=vs.100).aspx)

As noted in the comments below, `Except` has the added side effect of removing any duplicates in the source (`firstList` in this example).  This may or may not be an issue to you, but should be considered.

If keeping any duplicates in `firstList` is of importance, then this is the alternative:

```
var secondSet = new HashSet<Colour>(secondList, comparer);
var result = firstList.Where(c => !secondSet.Contains(c));
```

As before, `comparer` is optional if `Colour` implements appropriate equality

Comment: It seems like Except does not return duplicates (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/aa7687b8-34be-4268-a6ed-ba0641edf12f/linq-operators-except-also-behaves-like-distinct). This might not be an issue, but I just wanted to point out that this will not quite behave like the code posted by the OP.

Comment: Not _exactly_ the same as `Except` removes any duplicates from `firstList` and op's code does not. (Example `new[]{ 1,1,2}.Except(new[]{2})` will result in 1 not 1, 1)

Comment: Agree with duplicates concerns. Strictly speaking, this answer is wrong unless question is changed to use HashSet instead of List

Answer (score 3):

try the following:

```
var result = firstList.Where(x => !secondList.Any(y => y.ID == x.ID));
```

Edit:
If you care about runtime and don't mind creating your own `IEqualityComparer<>`, i would suggest you use `Except` like Charles suggested in his answer. `Except` seems to use a hashtable for the second list which speeds it up quite a bit compared to my `O(n*m)` query. However be aware that `Except` removes duplicates from `secondList` as well.

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer which produces the same result as the question for any input (i.e. including duplicates)