# Contains on two values?

Tags: c#

I've got a List properties that must contain both pivot1 and pivot2.

How can I make Contains work with BOTH values?

```
List<string> properties = line.Split('|').ToList();
string pivot1 = "value1";
string pivot2 = "value2";

if(properties.Contains(pivot1) && properties.Contains(pivot2))
{
// do stuff.

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520642/does-net-have-a-way-to-check-if-list-a-contains-all-items-in-list-b

Comment: What is wrong with the code you gave?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Because your `if` statement **does** already check if `properties` contains both `pivot1` and `pivot2`. Only thing is, it will throw a `NullReferenceException` as it is right now, because `properties` is declared, but not initialized.

Comment: Does your code not work? It looks like it checks that properties contains both items.

Comment: Are you just saying you want to pass both to `Contains` instead of calling `Contains` twice?  If so, that's not possible and what you have is IMO correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from writing an extension/helper method, you can use LINQ to shorten it a bit:

```
if (new[] { pivot1, pivot2 }.All(properties.Contains))
{

}
```

Although this is somewhat less readable I'd argue.

---

I personally like maintaining a Utility class to build up my own helpful framework to compliment .NET.  I'd do something like:

```
 public static bool ContainsAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, params T[] items)
 {
     foreach(var item in items)
     {
         if (!list.Contains(item))
             return false;
     }

     return true;
 }
```

then you can use:

```
if(properties.ContainsAll(pivot1, pivot2))
{

}
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution but I get the error: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS1106 Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class.

Comment: Extension methods must be in a static class.  I.e. public static class Utilities...

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing properties or adding anything to it.

```
List<string> properties = new List<string>();

properties.Add("value1");
properties.Add("value2");

string pivot1 = "value1";
string pivot2 = "value2";

if(properties.Contains(pivot1) && properties.Contains(pivot2))
{
    // do stuff.
}
```

Comment: don't think that was the point of the question at all