# Verify that a list has all the other list values

Tags: c#, linq, compare

I have 2 `int` arrays, arr1, and arr2 eg, what is the most efficient way to verify that the arr1 contains All items that arr2 contains. Preferentially returning `bool`.

eg.

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,9]
 //return true;

arr1 = [1,2,3,4,10]
arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,9]
 //return false;
```

I did It with `foreach` but I want anything besides brute-force foreach, if is possible.

Comment: Are the lists always sorted?

Comment: Top result for "c# list contains all" is this [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1520642/1324033)

Comment: list can be unsorted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about something like:

```
bool subset = !arr1.Except(arr2).Any();
```

Would probably be smoothly implemented as an extension method like this:

```
public static bool ContainsAll<T>(this List<T> list, List<T> other)
{
    return !other.Except(list).Any();
}
```

Usage would then be:

```
bool subset = arr2.ContainsAll(arr1);
```