# List contains list

Tags: c#, contains

Hi I have the following lists:

```
 var CustomerName = new List<Customer>();
 var DummyData = new List<Customer>();
```

How can I quickly check that DummyData is contained inside of CustomerName? Also performance is key as these lists might contain thousands of values.

Comment: Why does your question have a sql tag but is using lists for the two variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does .NET have a way to check if List a contains all items in List b?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520642/does-net-have-a-way-to-check-if-list-a-contains-all-items-in-list-b)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Brute Force Method

Use linq all method against the DummyData variable `O(N*K)`

```
// If you override Equals and GetHashCode or are comparing by reference
DummyData.All(a=>CustomerName.Contains(a))

//If you compare by property
DummyData.All(a=>
               CustomerName.Any(b=>
                   a.FirstName==b.FirstName && 
                   a.LastName == b.LastName
                   //repeat to include checks for all properties
              )
          );
```

### Using a HashSet

Put your results into a hashset and use linq's `All` method again checking if hashset contains items, takes N steps to build hashset and K steps to check, complexity is `O(N+K)`

```
var hs = new HashSet<Customer>(CustomerName);
DummyData.All(a=>hs.Contains(a));
```

### You will need to override Equals And GetHashCode

If you haven't overriden these two yet you'll need to unless you want to compare properties and this prevents you from using the hash set method as well

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var customer = obj as Customer;
        return customer != null && Equals(customer);
    }

    protected bool Equals(Customer other)
    {
        return string.Equals(FirstName, other.FirstName) && string.Equals(LastName, other.LastName);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((FirstName?.GetHashCode() ?? 0)*397) ^ (LastName?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would note that this uses _reference equality_ unless you're overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: Brute force doesn't work it returns false when I do a bool

Comment: @Elsid did you override the Equals and GetHashCode method? You'll need to do that regardless for both examples provided

Comment: Is there a way to do it without overriding Equals?

Comment: @Konkked there is no first name or last name, the list just contains the values returned to it. Example: CustomerName(0)="ABC Company" ect. ect.

Comment: @Elsid what is `Customer` then? Do you have a list of `Customer` or a list of `string`? If you put the class in your answer it will be easier for me to give you an exact answer

Comment: I have a field Name, when I ran it with Name bool contains returned false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114280/discussion-between-konkked-and-elsid).