# How to check if a string is contained in another list of strings?

Tags: c#

I have a list of folders in which I contain a list of languages that I want to be processed:

```
eng_US
spa_ES
```

etc...

I have a list of directories containing subfolders for each language it has. They can be more than the ones defined in my languages list. It can look like this:

```
ja-JP
eng_US
spa_Es
fr_FR
```

I list the directories in that specific folder like this:

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
```

I want to get with **Linq** all that folders that are inside my private language list.

I tried something similar to this:

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Where(x => x.Contains(languageList.Value));
```

But, obviously is bad :(

How can I get only the folders which are also listed in my private language list?

So, **how can I check if my resulting path is contained inside another string list with Linq?**

Thanks!

**NOTE:**
My language list is saved in a **Dictionary**.

```
IDictionary<int, string> languages;
```

Comment: "But, obviously is bad" — why do you think so?

Comment: Because it's not working and it's badly formatted. It doesn't even compile. I'm trying to use logic with Lynq, but not working...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does .NET have a way to check if List a contains all items in List b?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520642/does-net-have-a-way-to-check-if-list-a-contains-all-items-in-list-b)

Comment: It looks like that, but don't understand how to apply it... I'm using .Net 4.5

Comment: If you want to check (get a boolean result), there is a good answer below. However, if you want to get the intersection of two string lists, you should use exactly that: [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close - Remember `languageList` is a list of names you care about and your Linq statement will return one string value at a time to put through your `Where` clause, so you'd want it to look as follows:

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Where(x => languageList.Contains(x)).ToArray();
```

Basically saying `Give me back and returned value that is contained in languageList`

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Don't fall into his trap... `Where(...)` doesn't return `string[]` type

Comment: Don¡t worry! That was excatly! I returned a List :D

Comment: Glad it gave you what you needed!

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare on the directory name not the full path. Also you are checking if the directory path contains a value gotten from language list.

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path)
                                .Where(d => languageList.Contains(Path.GetFileName(d)))
                                .ToArray();
```

Note that you have to use `Path.GetFileName` as this will return 'endfolder' from 'C:\folder\endfolder'. Whereas `Path.GetDirectoryName` will return 'C:\folder'.