# select List where sub-list contains is all item from another list with linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a model with list items:

```
public class Student{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
}
```

The table values are similar to the following:

| StudentId | ClassId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | **8** |
| 2 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | **8** |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 1 | **6** |
| 3 | **6** |
| 2 | 2 |

classId list for filter:

| ClassId |
| --- |
| 8 |
| 6 |

I want to select the list of StudentId where are in all filter classId.

| StudentId |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |

I use this code but not working:

```
List<int> lstStudentId = Students.GroupBy(o => o.StudentId).Where(o => o.All(m => filterClassId.All(s => s == m.ClassId ))).Select(o => o.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: but the corresponding StudentId are 1,2 not 1,3

Comment: @mshwf: I want students include 6 and 8 classId.

Comment: Student 2 is not include ClassId 8.

Comment: The ClassId table in the question contains 8&6 not 3&8

Comment: @mshwf: I edited my answer to you

Comment: Ok got you. You can use Intersect:

`var eight = new int[]{1,3,4};
var six = new int[]{2,1,3};

var result = eight.Intersect(six);
foreach(var r in result)
    Console.WriteLine(r);`

Comment: @vernou: I tested similar to this and did not get an answer. Please give a more complete code

Comment: @mshwf: Please answer according to my question codes. I don't understand the usage of your code according to my question

Comment: Maybe similar to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520642/does-net-have-a-way-to-check-if-list-a-contains-all-items-in-list-b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write :

```cs
List<int> lstStudentId = Students
    .GroupBy(o => o.StudentId)
    .Where(o => o.All(m => filterClassId.All(s => s == m.ClassId)))
    .Select(o => o.Key).ToList();
```

The `Where` check all student's classes are in the filter... but you want the inverse, all filtered classes are in the student.

Just reverse the condition :

```cs
var lstStudentId = Students
    .GroupBy(o => o.StudentId)
    .Where(g => filterClassId.All(f => g.Any(s => s.ClassId == f)))
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToList();
```

A alternative, it's to check if the filter less the student's class result in nothing. Then the student has all class in the filter :

```cs
var lstStudentId = Students
    .GroupBy(o => o.StudentId)
    .Where(g => !filterClassId.Except(g.Select(s => s.ClassId)).Any())
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Intersect`, first implemet `IEqualityComparer` for the `Student` model:

```
class StudentComparer : IEqualityComparer<Student>
{
    public bool Equals(Student? x, Student? y) => x.StudenId == y.StudenId;
    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] Student obj) => obj.StudenId.GetHashCode();
}
```

Then you are able to use `Intersect` as follows:

```
var commonStudents = students.Where(x => x.ClassId == 8)
    .Intersect(students.Where(x => x.ClassId == 6), new StudentComparer())
    .Select(x => new { x.StudenId }).ToList();
```