# Using Linq Returning all records matching all from a list of parameters

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a simple table with CustomerID & ProductCode. Using the following Linq query I get a list of all IDs that bought 10EDUC **or** 12CONV and didn't buy 10CONV and 11CONV. What I need to do is get it to return the IDs for those that bought 10EDUC **and** 12CONV and didn't buy 10CONV and 11CONV.

Any thoughts?  TIA

```
var IncludePredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Products>(); 
var ExcludePredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Products>(); 
List<string> IncludeProducts = new List<string>();
List<string> ExcludeProducts = new List<string>();
ExcludeProducts.Add("10CONV");
ExcludeProducts.Add("11CONV");


IncludeProducts.Add("10EDUC");
IncludeProducts.Add("12CONV");
IncludePredicate = IncludePredicate.And(m=>IncludeProducts.Contains(m.Service));
ExcludePredicate = ExcludePredicate.And(m => ExcludeProducts.Contains(m.Service));
var IncludeResults = (from d in Products
                          .AsExpandable()
                          .Where(IncludePredicate)
                          .Distinct()
                              select d.CustomerID
                              )
                              .Except(from ex in Services
                                          .Where(ExcludePredicate)
                                          select ex.CustomerID);
```

Comment: The imprecision of the 'and' and 'or' in the English language gets in the way here: by "and didn't buy 10CONV and 11CONV", do you mean "did not buy either 10CONV or 11CONV", or "may have bought 10CONV or 11CONV, but not 10CONV and 11CONV together"?

Comment: I think we can disregard the Exclude products to simplify things. I need to return only IDs for people who bought both 10EDUC and 12CONV.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ: Check whether an Array is a subset of another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/linq-check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another)

Comment: Risky, that works with two lists/arrays but not with multiple records coming back from a DB. At least I can't seem to get it to work.