# How to match a sequence in a List with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible using LINQ to test for a match of a sequence of list items? e.g.

```
var masterList = new List<string>{"fox", "jumps", "dog"};
var childList1 = new List<string>{"fox", "jumps"};
var childList2 = new List<string>{"fox", "dog"};
```

I'd like to write something such that looking for childList1 in masterList is true, but childList2 is false, because there's something in between.

EDIT: {"jumps", "dog"} would also match.

Comment: Little round about, but if [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546153.aspx) of both lists is equal to the child list length, then it is contained in the master list.

Comment: @KyleMit Intersect isn't too awesome here because it will produce a new `IEnumberable` you could then check that it is the same as the childList, but it's not really ideal. You end up where you started if it is a subset.

Comment: Does it have to match _any_ sequence or do they both have to _start_ with the same values?  Meaning would `{"jumps", "dog"}` match, too?

Comment: Yes, {"jumps", "dog"} should also be a match.

Comment: Would `{"fox", "dog"};` not be a match since there is a value between fox and dog in master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is similar to Andrei's but may be faster since it looks for the first item in the parent list to limit the number of searches:

```
public bool SubsequenceEquals<T>(IEnumerable<T> masterList, IEnumerable<T> childList)
{
    // find all indexes 
    var matches = masterList.Select((s, i) => new {s, i})
                            .Where(m => m.s.Equals(childList.First()))
                            .Select (m => m.i);

    return matches.Any(m => Enumerable.SequenceEqual(childList, masterList
                                                           .Skip(m)
                                                           .Take(childList.Count())));
}
```

Comment: This won't be faster (is likely to be about 50% slower I would say) because it will have to iterate the master list twice (up to the first occurrence of the first element from childlist, plus it will need to call `childList.First()` for every iteration. And I personally also don't like creating temporary objects unnecessarily. All this is unnecessary because SequenceEquals stops iterating both sequences as soon as it hits first mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

If exact sequence of elements is important try something like:

```
public static bool ListContains<T>(List<T> source, List<T> search)
{
    if (search.Count > source.Count)
        return false;

    return Enumerable.Range(0, source.Count - search.Count + 1)
        .Select(a => source.Skip(a).Take(search.Count))
        .Any(a => a.SequenceEqual(search));
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var masterList = new List<string> { "fox", "jumps", "dog" };
    var childList1 = new List<string> { "fox", "jumps" };
    var childList2 = new List<string> { "fox", "dog" };

    Console.WriteLine(ListContains(masterList, childList1));
    Console.WriteLine(ListContains(masterList, childList2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another question that has a working answer; [Check whether an array is a subset of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/linq-check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another)

```
bool isSubest = !childList1.Except(masterList).Any();
```

will do it for you. You could also do

```
  if (childList1.Except(masterList).Count > 0)
      // items in child not in master
  else
       //child is a subest of master
```

Comment: OP is asking for sequence I think

Comment: @SriramSakthivel meaning they have to be in the same order? The results of LINQ queries are often referred to as 'sequences' so I was not really sure what he meant by that.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I didn't know the word sequences had implications!