# In C#, What is the best way to see if a list contains another list?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

If i have a list of strings, what is the best way to determine if every element in another list is contains in this list.  For example:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Dog");
list.Add("Cat");
list.Add("Bird");

List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
list.Add("Dog");
list.Add("Cat");

if (list.ContainsList(list2))
{
      Console.Write("All items in list2 are in list1")
}
```

I am trying to determine if there something like this "ContainsList" method?

Comment: Good discussion here on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/linq-check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another  @leora

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (!list2.Except(list).Any())
```

Answer (score 4):

Loved SLaks version. Just for completeness, you can use `HashSet` method [IsSubsetOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358446.aspx) when performing set operations (also check `IsSupersetOf` method). There are pros and cons for this approach. Next code shows an example:

```
var list1 = new HashSet<string>{ "Dog", "Cat", "Bird" };

var list2 = new HashSet<string>{ "Dog", "Cat" };

if (list2.IsSubsetOf(list1))
{
      Console.Write("All items in list2 are in list1");
}
```

`Except` method is streaming in nature. In query `list2.Except(list1)` `list1` is buffered completely into memory, and you iterate one item at a time through `list2`. `IsSubsetOf` works eagerly in the opposite manner. This starts to make a difference when you have huge sets of data.

---

To analyse the worst case performance, here is some code from `Except` implementation at [Monos Enumerable](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs) (dotPeek gives very similar results, just less readable)

```
var items = new HashSet<TSource> (second, comparer);  //list1.Count

foreach (var element in first)                        //list2.Count
    if (items.Add (element))                          //constant time
        yield return element;
```

as result `O(list1.Count + list2.Count)`, loops aren't nested.

`IsSubset` has next method call, if second `IEnumerable` is `HashSet` (decompiled via dotPeek):

```
private bool IsSubsetOfHashSetWithSameEC(HashSet<T> other)
{
    foreach (T obj in this)         //list2.Count
        if (!other.Contains(obj))   //constant time
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Resulting in `O(list2.Count)` if `list1` is a `HashSet`.

Comment: Using Linq's `Except()` is an O(mn) operation, I believe, whilst `HashSet.IsSubsetOf()` is O(n).

Comment: @NicholasCarey well, depends on definitions. `Except` takes two `IEnumerable`s, construct `HashSet` from right and iterates over left calling `Add` method on `HashSet`. This gives `m + n`, as far as I can see. `Add` method takes constant time. `IsSubset` has this line `HashSet<T> hashSet = other as HashSet<T>;` which makes a huge difference removing the need to construct `HashSet` from `list1`. Then it left only with `O(n)` indeed, where n = `list1.Count`.

Comment: @NicholasCarey `Enumerable.Except` actually creates a temporary hash table during enumeration. That makes it O(n+m), not O(nm).

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
var list1 = new List<string>{"Dog","Cat","Bird"};
var list2 = new List<string>{"Dog","Cat"};

if (list1.Union(list2).SequenceEqual(list1))
    Console.Write("All items in list2 are in list1");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
list1.intersect (list2).ToList ().Foreach ((x)=>
{
Console.Writeline (x)
});
```