# C# - Array2 contains Array1 ignore order

Tags: c#, arrays, compare

Where should I look if I want to write a piece of code which looks for Array1 in Array2, regardless of the order (keeping the duplicates in mind)?
e.g.

```
Array1: { 2,5,6,6,3 }
Array2: { 1,2,3,4,5,6,6 }
will return true


Array1: { 2,5,6,6,3 }
Array2: { 1,2,3,4,5,6 }
will return false
```

I sort of want to solve it myslef, I just need to be pointed in some direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your logic. Your first example certainly *looks* like it is contained, and the other *could* be if you ignore duplicates.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "keep the duplicities in mind"?

Comment: Fixed wording. Means that if Array1 contains an element more times, it'll have to find it at least that number of times to return true. EDIT: Also fixed the swapped true/false. My fault.

Comment: Duplicate/related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another

Comment: As a hint: Use a `Dictionary<int, int>` and store the quantity (used as value) of each number (used a key) of Array2.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I don't think that question deals with duplicates in the way the OP wants.

Comment: That might be the problem. English is my second language and I sort of didn't know the meaning of "subset" in this context. Thank you. Working for arrays as well, or do I have to convert?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: This is not duplicate, since this solution does not take into account the number of occurrences of the numbers.

Comment: Arrays are `IEnumerable` so the LINQ solution will work out of the box. You will have to deal with the duplicate problem though.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Agreed, not an actual duplicate (didn't VTC). Still related though, and may give the "hint" he is looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you only want hints rather than code, one method would be:

1. Copy `array2` into a `List<int>`.
2. [Sort it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
3. Allocate a [bit array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) called `used` equal to the size of the list.  These will be flags indicating whether a specific item in the sorted list has been used for a match.
4. For each item `item` in `array1`:

   4.1 [Binary search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the sorted list for `item`.

   4.2. If not found, return false -- `array2` does not contain `array1`.

   4.3. If found, and there are duplicates, the binary search algorithm will randomly return the index of one of the duplicates.  Scan backward in the portion of the list that matches `item` until you find one for which `used[i]` is false.  If you find one, set `used[i]` to true, and continue the outer loop.  If you don't find one, scan forward from the initial binary search index, trying to find an unused match.  Similarly set `used[index]` to true if one is found, and continue looping through `array1`.

   4.4 If no unused match is found, return false -- `array2` does not contain `array1`.
5. Having found an unused match for each item in `array1`, return true: `array1` is contained inside `array2`.

An advantage of this algorithm is that, to check multiple arrays for being contained in a given array, you don't need to re-sort the array every time, you only need to re-allocate the `BitArray`.