# DbQuery behaves differently in a foreach loop. Why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

If I use the following code, I get a list of students that study course 1 and course 2. (This is almost what I want.)

```cs
IQueryable<Student> filteredStudents = context.Students;
filteredStudents = filteredStudents
    .Where(s => s.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID).Contains(1));
filteredStudents = filteredStudents
    .Where(s => s.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID).Contains(2));
List<Student> studentList = filteredStudents.ToList<Student>();
```

However, if I try and do this in a foreach loop (as shown in the following code) then I get a list of all students that are signed up for the last course in the loop.

```cs
IQueryable<Student> filteredStudents = context.Students;
foreach (Course course in filter.Courses) {
    if (course != null) {             
        filteredStudents = filteredStudents
            .Where(s => s.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID).Contains(course.CourseID));
    }
}
List<Student> studentList = filteredStudents.ToList<Student>();
```

This behaviour confuses me. Can anyone explain why this is happening? And how to get around it? Thank you.

Comment: the `.Select(s => s)` is unneeded by the way, `Student` is already selected by default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the foreach loop only creates a *single* `course` variable for all of the loop iterations, and this single variable is then captured into a closure. Also remember that the filters aren't actually executed until after the loop. Put those together, and by the time the filters execute this single `course` variable has advanced to the last item in the Courses filter; you only check against that one last course.

I see four ways to fix the problem.

### First

Create a new variable for each iteration of the loop (this is probably your best quick fix)

```
IQueryable<Student> filteredStudents = context.Students;
foreach (Course course in filter.Courses) {
    if (course != null) {  
        int CourseID = course.CourseID;            
        filteredStudents = filteredStudents
            .Where(s => s.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID).Contains(CourseID));
    }
}
List<Student> studentList = filteredStudents.ToList<Student>();
```

### Second

Resolve the IEnumerable expression inside the loop (probably much less efficient):

```
IEnumerable<Student> filteredStudents = context.Students;
foreach (Course course in filter.Courses) {
    if (course != null) {             
        filteredStudents = filteredStudents
            .Where(s => s.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID).Contains(course.CourseID))
            .ToList(); 
    }
}
List<Student> studentList = filteredStudents.ToList<Student>();
```

### Third

Use more appropriate linq operators/lambda expressions to eliminate the foreach loop:

```
var studentList = context.Students.Where(s => s.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID).Intersect(filter.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID)).Any()).ToList();
```

Or in a more readable way:

```
IQueryable<Student> filteredStudents = context.Students;
var courses = filter.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID);
var studentList = filteredStudents
       .Where(s => s.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID)
                       .Intersect(courses)
                       .Any()
       ).ToList();
```

If you play with this a bit, the performance should meet or ***far exceed***  the foreach loop through clever internal use of HashSets or — if you're very lucky — by sending a JOIN query to the DB). Just be careful, because it's easy to write something here that make numerous "extra" calls out to the DB inside that `Intersect()` or `Any()` method. Even so, this is the option I tend to prefer, with the exception that I probably wouldn't bother to call `.ToList()` at the end.

This also illustrates why I don't have much use for ORMs like Entity Framework, linq-to-sql, or even NHibernate or ActiveRecord. If I'm just writing SQL, I can *know* I'm getting the correct join query. I could do that with an ORM, too, but now I *still* need to know about the specific SQL I'm creating, and I also have to know how to get the ORM to do what I want.

### Fourth

Use C# 5.0. [This is fixed in the most recent version of C#](http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/), so that each iteration of a for/foreach loop is its own variable.

Comment: I just tried your third method, but it doesn't give the desired result. It returns Students that have "any" of the courses in the filter. I would like it to return Students that have "all" of the courses in the filter.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get every `Student` that is enrolled in every course in `filter.Courses`, you could try:

```cs
var courseIDs = filter.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID);
var filteredStudents = context.Students
    .Where(s => !courseIDs.Except(s.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseId)).Any())
```

which filters on whether `courseIDs` is a [subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another) of a `Student`'s course IDs.

**Edit**

[Joel Coehoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30405158/4812586) and [Mikael Eliasson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30404953/4812586) give a good explanation for why all of the students in the last course were retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Because "filteredStudents = filteredStudents.Where..." is a straight assignment to the variable, each time through the loop you are completely replacing what was in it before. you need to append to it, not replace.  Try a search for "c# AddRange"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has to do with Entity Framework. It's a bug (not really, but a stupid design in c#) where the variable is declared outside the loop.

In this case it means that because the IEnumerable is lazily evaluated it will use the LAST value of the variable. Use a temp variable in the loop to solve it.

```
foreach (Course course in filter.Courses) {
    if (course != null) {
        var cId = course.CourseID;       
        filteredStudents = filteredStudents
            .Where(s => s.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID).Contains(cId))
                .Select(s => s);
    }
}
```

Or even better if you have the navigation properties properly defined. Just do:

```
var studentList = filter.Courses.SelectMany(c => c.Students).ToList()
```

See more info here: [Is there a reason for C#'s reuse of the variable in a foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach)