# EF Intersect Syntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

A UI allows users to select one or many tags.  I would like to select all Nodes that have ALL that tags the user entered associated, **not** just a single tag.

```
public JsonResult SearchNodesByTags(string[] tags)
{
    var dbTags = _DbContext.Tags.Where(t => tags.Contains(t.DisplayName)).ToList();
    var nodes = _DbContext.Nodes.Where(n => n.Tags.Intersect(dbTags).Any());  
    // Error about intersection with non primitive

    return Json(nodes);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this in one statement:

```
var nodes = _DbContext.Nodes
            .Where(n => n.Tags.All(t => tags.Contains(t.DisplayName)));
```

Your statement is not correct because `dbTags` is a local list containing `Tag` objects. When you use this list in a LINQ-to-Entities expression there is no way to translate these objects into SQL variables. That's only possible with primitive values.

Comment: That worked, you just forgot the:
**t =>** tags.Contains(t.DisplayName)

If you modify this, I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Actually, I am getting a circular reference problem now.  This is probably because I have a many to many relationship between Nodes and Tags.

Comment: I'd propose you put this into a new question, because I need more details to see what exactly is going on. I don't know where/how you get this circular reference problem.

Comment: I solved that problem, however, it seems that I am getting the incorrect result.  Here is my query:

var nodes = _DbContext.Nodes.Where(n => n.Tags.All(t => tags.Contains(t.DisplayName))).Select(n => new {n.NodeNativeId, n.NodeName, n.NodeClass.ClassName}).ToList();

I am getting back a node that isn't associated with the tag.  It also happens to be the name with the highest ID.

Comment: Again, please ask a new question if subsequent issues arise. It's very hard to read code in comments and it's impossible to give enough details. For instance, "incorrect results" needs lots more explanation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948048/ef-linq-return-entities-that-contain-an-entire-collection

Comment: @jjj See my comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948048/ef-linq-return-entities-that-contain-an-entire-collection#comment49936049_30948285)

Comment: @GertArnold: ah I think I see what you were trying to do. Something like `.Where( n => tags.All(t => n.Tags.Select(t2 => t2.DisplayName).Contains(t)))`? Not sure if that would work with SQL generation though...and I'm on the wrong computer to try that out. I was more pointing out that your answer wouldn't quite give what the OP wanted.

Comment: @jjj That would create a query with as many `UNION`s as tags. Better than `n` `UINION`s with single row queries that `EXCEPT` produces, but still not too good. Anyway, it all depends on the meaning of "all" how this should be implemented in the end. There are three meanings of "all" equivalent to left outer join, full join or right outer join. I'm thinking of writing an answer that brings it all together and also elaborates on effects on query shape. (To OP's second question, but begging not to accept it. It's no competition, I just like the collegial discourse we have about the subject).

Comment: Come to think of it, this question will be a good place for it as well.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> var nodes = _DbContext.Nodes.Where(n => n.Tags.Intersect(dbTags).Any());
> ```

First of all, you can't use objects in a Linq-to-Entities expression, so you'd have to use something like this to compare:

```
n.Tags.Select(t => t.DisplayName).Intersect(tags)
```

Second, `Intersect` will give you the set of items that are in both given sets, so you'll end up with all `Node`s that has *any* of the tags, instead of all nodes that have *all* of the tags.

---

If you want all the `Node`s that contain every `Tag` in `tags`, you might want to use the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another) on subsets:

```
_DbContext.Nodes
    .Where(n => !tags.Except(n.Tags.Select(t => t.DisplayName)).Any()) 
    .Select(...
```

- `set1.Except(set2)` contains elements of `set1` that aren't in `set2`
- `!set1.Except(set2).Any() == true` if `set2` includes every element of `set1`