# EF LINQ - Return entities that contain an entire collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to troubleshoot the following LINQ Query:

```
public JsonResult SearchNodesByTags(string[] tags)
{    

    var nodes = _DbContext.Nodes.
            Where(n => n.Tags.All(t => tags.Contains(t.DisplayName)))
            .Select(n => new {n.NodeNativeId, n.NodeName, n.NodeClass.ClassName})
            .ToList();

    return Json(nodes);
}
```

The query is returning a single node that is not associated with a tag.  What I want it to do, is return any nodes that have ALL the tags.

Comment: You have to add `n.Tags.Any() && n.Tags.All(...`. That eliminates nodes without tags. I don't see how the query can't return any nodes if there really are existing tags in the `tags` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>   .Where(n => n.Tags.All(t => tags.Contains(t.DisplayName)))
> ```

The way this is currently constructed, you're only going to end up with the `Node`s where *every* tag in `Node.Tags` has a name in the `tags` whitelist, which includes `Node`s with no tags.

---

You might want to use the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another) on subsets:

```
_DbContext.Nodes
    .Where(n => !tags.Except(n.Tags.Select(t => t.DisplayName)).Any()) 
    .Select(...
```

- `set1.Except(set2)` contains elements of `set1` that aren't in `set2`
- `!set1.Except(set2).Any() == true` if `set2` includes every element of `set1`

---

**Edit**

It was pointed out in the comments that using Except could generate problematic queries, so I was thinking another option was to get a superset from the database, and further filter the objects within the application:

```
_DbContext.Nodes
    // filter nodes with any of the input tags
    .Where(n => n.Tags.Any(t => tags.Contains(t.DisplayName)))

    // select the information required
    .Select(n => new {
        n.NodeNativeId, 
        n.NodeName, 
        ClassName = n.NodeClass.ClassName,
        TagNames = n.Tags.Select(t => t.DisplayName) })

    // materialize super set with database
    .ToList()

    // filter so that only nodes with all tags remain
    .Where(n => !tags.Except(n.TagNames).Any())

    // produce result in anonymous class
    .Select(n => new { n.NodeNativeId, n.NodeName, n.ClassName })
    .ToList();
```

---

**Edit 2**

I just saw another one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30985573/4812586) that might work for you, but it requires that `Tag.DisplayName` is ***unique***, since it could fail if you have multiple tags with the same `DisplayName`:

```
_dbContext.Nodes
     .Where(n => n.Tags.Count(t => tags.Contains(t.DisplayName)) == tags.Count)
     .Select(...
```

Comment: Did you check the query that's generated using `Except`? `Except` with local lists generates terrible queries that quickly exceed maximum nesting level. I've learned to stay away from it.

Comment: @GertArnold: ah I didn't know that. In that case maybe it would be better to pull down a superset and do further filtering using linq-to-objects.

Comment: I would like to implement the Edited answer, however, it seems that there are some syntax errors there.  The select on line 3 is not valid.

Comment: @blgrnboy: Ah yeah, it should be `Select(t => t.DisplayName)` to get names, and not `Select(t.DisplayName)`

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, after n.Tags.Any(t => tags.Contains(t.DisplayName))   -   .Select is not valid here.

Comment: @blgrnboy: oooooh, I'm missing a closing parenthesis after the `Any`...the `Select` is supposed to build off the `Where`