# Contains At Least All in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have the following 2 entitys in my db.

```
public class Article
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Some code removed for brevity

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}


public class Tag
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Some code removed for brevity

    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }

}
```

I need to filter these articles based on the tag IDs that are passed into my action.

```
public ActionResult FindAll(List<int> tags)
{

    //
    // I need to return all articles which have ALL the tags passed into this method
    //

    var query = ApplicationDbContext.Articles...


}
```

For example, if I passed in 1, 2, 3 into the action, only articles which had these 3 tags or more would be returned.

How can I achieve this?

**Thanks for the great response!**

All your answers produced the correct result so I did some quick, basic profiling in sql and this was the results based on your queries.

[image: Query Results]

Comment: For those `Except` and `All` answers, you might want to check to make sure the performance is acceptable for the load you're expecting, and that the generated SQL still works if `tags.Count` is large. See the comments under [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947278/ef-intersect-syntax/30948394#comment49949396_30947688) for more details. It *might* be worth querying a superset of articles (with any of the tags?) and further filtering.

Comment: if none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Comment: I'm curious: how many tags did you use for these tests, how large was the `Articles` table, and how large was the result set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**Except()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx) and [**Any()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) like

```
ApplicationDbContext
    .Articles
    .Where(a => tags.Except( a.Tags.Select( t => t.Id ).ToList() ).Any() == false)
```

`Except()` will give you the items from the first list which **do not** exist in the second list

> The Except operator produces the set difference between two sequences.
>   It will only return elements in the **first** sequence that don't appear
>   in the second.

Comment: This only works for articles that have only the matching tags and no more.... right?

Comment: I don't think this does what the OP wants as he stated he wants *at least* the tags specified, not *only*.

Comment: @adam0101, ive corrected my answer and it should work based off http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620266/the-opposite-of-intersect

Comment: Looks like yours works now... nice solution. I tried to come up with a 1 liner and failed.  +1

Comment: The article tag is an object with an Id property, not an integer. I think you need to tweak this a little more.

Comment: I'd be curious to see how the execution plan differs between this and my solution. If this were Linq-to-entities, I would expect mine to run faster because this one looks at every tag in the article to get the Id where as mine would exit the loop as soon as it found all the necessary tags, but SQL Server is a different animal.

Comment: @AmmarCSE Thank you for your answer. For some reason I expected SQL to generate two queries since you're enumerating the tags by calling ToList but it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
ApplicationDbContext.Articles.Where(a => tags.All(t => a.Tags.Any(at => at.Id == t)));
```

Comment: I never even knew an `All` existed. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  var query =from a in ApplicationDbContext.Articles
             where a.Tags.Count(t => tags.Contains(t.Id)) == tags.Count
             select a;
```

Comment: I think your first revision was correct. This is now matching the exact number of tags, which isn't what the OP wanted.

Comment: @adam0101, the first query returned the articles with at least one tag that matches in the tags list. Now, with the second query I'm not just checking the number of tags are the same, check the condition in the subquery, if the amount of contained tags matches with amount of elements in the `tags` list, then I select the article

Comment: `where a.Tags.Count(t => tags.Contains(t.Id)) == tags.Count` ?

Answer (score 1):

Iteratively building the result through IQueryable.

```
public ActionResult FindAll(List<int> tags)
{
    var queryable = ApplicationDbContext.Articles.AsQueryable();

    foreach(var t in tags)
    {
        queryable = queryable.Where(w => w.Tags.Any(a => a.Id == t));
    }

    queryable.AsEnumerable();   // stuff this into a viewmodel and return actionresult?
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I saw in another comment you tried to do this as a one liner. This is possible using the Aggregate method. tags.Aggregate(ApplicationDbContext.CaseStudies.AsQueryable(), (current, t) => current.Where(w => w.Tags.Any(a => a.Id == t)));

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var articles = ApplicationDbContext.Articles.Where (a => a.Tags.Select (t => t.Id).Intersect(tags).Count()>=tags.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
ApplicationDbContext.Articles.Where(a => tags.All(t => a.Tags.Contains(t)));
```

Comment: This isn't correct. He wants to match all the specified tags, not all the tags on the article.

Comment: That looks right now except that the article tag is an object with an Id property, not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying this and receiving the error *"... could not be translated"*, it seems that `.All()` doesn't work on in-memory collections such as those from API query parameters. One solution is first convert `tags` to IQueryable e.g.:

```
var tags = ApplicationDbContext.Tags.Where(t => tags.Contains(t.Id));
var query = ApplicationDbContext.Articles
    .Where(a => tags.All(t => a.Tags.Contains(t)));
```

Another solution is to use .Count and .Contains instead of .All:

```
var query = ApplicationDbContext.Articles
    .Where(a => a.Tags.Count(t => tags.Contains(t.Id)) == tags.Count());
```