# How to check for the absence of any value in a list from a set server-side in LINQ? (SQL given)

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Given a property `foo` of an entity `bar` for which the entity set contains a large number of values, how can we check for the absence (from `bar`) of *any* value in an arbitrary list of values, using LINQ-to-Entities?

For example:

- `bar` contains `ALPHA` and `BETA`.
- We have a list of three items: `[ALPHA, BETA, GAMMA]` which we want to send to the EF backend (DBMS). We expect the backend to reply with a single scalar result (1 or 0 / true or false).  In this case, it would return 0, since at least one value is absent (`GAMMA`).
- If *all* values from the list are in the entity set, the query would return 1. For example, when the list is: `[ALPHA, BETA]` or simply `[ALPHA]` or `[BETA]`.
- We definitely don't want to transfer the whole entity set to the EF client.
- We definitely don't want to issue multiple queries for each value in the list.

---

Example dynamic T-SQL:

```
select case when not exists (
    select * from (
        select 'ALPHA' foo
        union select 'BETA' foo
        union select 'GAMMA' foo) a
    left join (select distinct foo from bar) b
    on a.foo = b.foo
    where b.foo is null)
    then 1
    else 0
end;
```

How could we formulate a LINQ-to-Entity query that would generate this SQL query (or equivalent)?

*Note: I wrote this SQL query in the most natural way I could think of (it literally reads like "check that there is no value in the list for which there is no corresponding value in the `bar` table").  It's very likely there's a better way to do this.*

Comment: Reminds me of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984564/contains-at-least-all-in-entity-framework

Comment: @jjj Indeed, it's almost a dupe if not for the "return a boolean" requirement. It brings an interesting problem regarding the context of LINQ operations (L2E vs L2O) though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `All` method

This will give you the correct answer, but it will result in a query for each item in list.

```
var list = new[] { "ALPHA", "BETA", "GAMMA" };

bool result = list.All(f => ctx.Bars.Any(b => b.Foo == f));
```

---

However, if you write it as a subselect, it will generate a single query.

```
bool result = 
    ctx.Bars.Select(x => 

              list.All(f => ctx.Bars.Any(b => b.Foo == f)) //Same as above but encapsulated 

            ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Notice that `ctx.Bars.Select(x =>`  is never actually used and it's only purpose is to encapsulate your `All` logic.

---

Another option is to use `SelectMany` on the context and then selecting only the list. The query sytnax looks like this:

```
bool result = 
    (from b in ctx.Bars
     from l in list
     select l).All(f => ctx.Bars.Any(b => b.Foo == f));
```

So like the solution above, we are only using `from b in ctx.Bars` to force the query to be an `IQueryable` expression rather than an `IEnumerable`. Which will generate 1 query, rather than `N` queries

Comment: That's not quite right. That returns true if and only if every `bar` in the table has `foo` set to one of the listed values. The OP wants to determine whether all of the listed values have at least one corresponding `bar` in the table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I *believe* my question is precise, but I definitely should have added the following example: list [A, B], bar set [A, B, D]. Unless I'm reading this wrong your answer would fail even though all items of the *list* are in the bar set. Now that I'm thinking about it in terms of `All`, inverting things would seem to procure the right semantics: `list.All(f => ctx.Bars.Any(b => b.Foo == f))`. Yet, I fear it wouldn't generate the right SQL: I expect it'll generate multiple queries. I'll try and report tomorrow.

Comment: -- Oh, you beat me to my comment.

Comment: @tne sorry I misread the question. I updated the answer, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: That's certainly creative. I'm not sure I like it *too* much yet, but I'll come around; type-safety benefits outweigh the POLA violation. A close-ish variant with Except+Any inspired by @jjj's post compiles a little cleaner: `ctx.Bars.Select(_ => list.Except(ctx.Bars.Select(b => b.Foo)).Any())` and intuitively *seems* like it could be faster. Yet, the query planner still *slightly* favors your version by 2%. It'd be really great if we could avoid the Select+First trick somehow, unless you know of an existing enhancement request, I might write one.

Comment: I commend your trickery skills. Your last edit, while still looking odd, actually generates a seemingly optimal request (almost identical to the one suggested by @RichardDeeming). We'll continue to research a few options for a bit, but it's very likely we'll end up using that. Thanks again!

Comment: @tne - It all boils down to using an `IQueryable` first and then the list (`IEnumerable`). So I guess the choice depends on what you prefer - readability or optimized sql generation.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Something like this?</strike>

```
bool result = !context.Bars.Any(b => list.Contains(b.Foo));
```

**EDIT**: The only option I can see is to use a raw SQL query. This will limit which back-end DBMS you can use, since different database systems support different syntax.

You'll also need to hard-code the table and column names - they won't get picked up if you refactor your code.

Assuming Microsoft SQL Server, something like this should work:

```
var list = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };

// Generate a parameter placeholder for each item in the list:
var listParameters = list.Select((item, index) => "@p" + index);

// Generate a "UNION" query for the parameters:
string listValues = string.Join(" UNION SELECT ", listParameters);

// The final query to execute:
string query = @"SELECT CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM (SELECT " + listValues + @") As L (foo)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM bar As b
        WHERE b.foo = L.foo
    )
) THEN CAST(1 As bit) ELSE CAST(0 As bit) END";

bool result = context.Database.SqlQuery<bool>(query, list).First();
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. For some reason this is the first thing I tried too (maybe it *sounds* right with `Any` in there) but quickly you realize it doesn't do what's intended: considering the [A, B, C] list with the [A, B] bar set, `Any` will stop at A since it's contained in the list, then invert the result without even considering C. In this case it yields the right answer by chance, but now consider: [A, B] list and [A, B] bar set. This should yield true, but doesn't. Unless I'm really tired moving the negation to the predicate isn't right either.

Comment: @tne: OK, I can see the problem. I can't see any way to fix it with EF directly - the only options I can come up with involve either making one query per item in the local list, or pulling back all of the `foo` values into memory. You might have to drop to raw SQL for this one.

Comment: On the one hand, I feared that was the case, on the other, I thought I was losing my mojo (it *sounds* so simple) so that's reassuring. I'll leave this open for a bit just in case we're both having a bad day, but feel free to add another "no can do" answer if you want.

Comment: @tne: OK, it's not clean, but the updated answer should do what you need.

Comment: For now your answer is technically the most exact one, despite its obvious disadvantages. Aducci's requires a tricky wrapping construct that will be reflected in the compiled SQL, and jjj's requires the backend to return a count instead of a boolean. I also like the double `EXISTS` better than a outer join.

Answer (score 1):

I'm borrowing an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30985573/4812586) but maybe you could do something like:

```cs
var itemList = new List<string> { ... };

// select just foo
var result = context.Bars.Select(b => b.Foo)
   // get the distinct values of foo
   .Distinct()
   // count how many values of foo are in itemList and check if the counts are equal
   // because the query is distinct, the count would match iff all items were matched
   .Count(f => itemList.Contains(f)) == itemList.Count;
```

The question for the answer I linked does also include other options that could be adapted for your case, like using `Except` with `Any`.

Comment: Thanks for that link, this is the entry point I missed while researching. While your solution doesn't *technically* answer the exact question (returns a count instead of a boolean value), for all intents and purposes it will work great with the appropriate performance signature. For kicks I tried the Except+Any approach coupled with Aducci's trick to have it run in the backend, it seems to work fine. I've read your discussions with @GertArnold regarding Except where he mentions issues with nesting levels; yet the generated query *looks* good to me. Are UNIONs considered to nest queries maybe?

Comment: Additional info: The distinct is actually compiled to a distinct-sort with a T-SQL backend, which has a bit of a cost compared to other approaches (e.g. @Aducci's). Unless there's something I missed I'm tempted to go with Except+Any or All(Any), even though they supposedly require that weird trick to be handled in the context of L2E.

Comment: @tne: I think it's also possible that the SQL generation for `Except` has been optimized since he had last looked at it