# How to check whether each item of an array exist in another array in mvc 4?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have two string arrays for example `selPhoto["419","418"]` and `preview_photo["418"]`.I need to  check whether each element in `selPhoto` present in 
`preview_photo` or not in mvc4.

Comment: _"Insufficient data for meaningful answer"_  - Isaac Asimov. Any code to show?

Comment: what is the code you have written for this so far?

Comment: Hmmm...the person who upvoted this should perhaps read _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_ along with the OP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check whether an array is a subset of another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var y = new[] { "419", "418" };
var x = new[] { "418" };
```

Check for intersection

```
x.Intersect(y).Contains("418");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if one array is a subset of another:

```
bool isSubset = !array2.Except(array1).Any();
```

So it would be like

```
bool isSubset = !preview_photo.Except(selPhoto).Any();
```

You can try to create an extension method as well for this

```
public static bool isSubset<T>(this IEnumerable<T> arr1, IEnumerable<T> arr2)
{
    return !arr1.Except(arr2).Any();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Except` and check to see if there are any items in the resulting set

```
var containsAllElements = !preview_photo.Except(selPhoto).Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult AddtoCart(string selPhoto, string preview_photo)
        {

    string[] values = selPhoto.Split(',');
    string[] photo = preview_photo.Split(',');
    foreach (var item in values)
    {
        if (photo.Contains(item))
        {
          // do action item in second array
        }

        else
        {
         //do action item not in second array
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var y = new[] { "419", "418" };
var x = new[] { "418" };
bool present=y.ToList().TrueForAll(a=>x.Contains(a));
```

however its always good to show what you have tried