# c# comparing two lists of integers in c#

Tags: c#

I have two lists that is

```
List<int> comments ;
List<int> no_checks;
```

Now i would like to see if all no_checks have comments. So during my processing of data whenever a comment is added am adding its id to comment list and when a no radio is selected am adding its id to no_checks

So a sample output to console has

1.

```
 below should return false;
 comment=[12, 13,15]
 no_checks = [12,13,15,17 ] //one no has no comment
```

2

```
 below should return true  
 comment=[12, 13,15]
 no_checks = [12,13 ] //all have comments
```

So am stuck here

```
public bool allnoHaveComments(){
 var allhave=true;

 for(var i=0; i<no_checks.count; i++){ 
    //if one no_checks is not contained in comments allhave=false

  }
  return allhave;
 }
```

How can i proceed to compare and check to see that id's in no_checks are all contained in comments else if they are not return false

How can i go about this

Comment: Does order matter? If not, then you might consider using `HashSet<int>` instead of `List<int>`.  A hashset represents a set of unordered things, and directly supports operations like the one you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool isallnoHaveComments= !no_checks.Except(comment).Any();
```

Comment: You should mention about how is a comment created by no one :))

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the values in no_checks that aren't in comments

```
no_checks.Except(comments)
```

Your problem is basically [Check whether an array is a subset of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another).