# MongoDB C# 2.4.4 Filter documents where all elements of a string array are in another array

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, filter, aggregation-framework

I'm working with le latest C# MongoDB driver (2.4.4). I cannot find a way to filter a collection where all elements of a string array property are in another array (as an input parameter).

data  : ["a", "b"] - input : ["a", "c", "b"] => OK

data  : ["a", "b"] - input : ["a", "c"] => KO

Here is a ligh version of my model.
I have a collection of shipments, each shipment has a string array of functions and subDocument array of shippingDocuments. Each shippingDocument also has a string array of functions.

```
shipment[]
   reference
   functions[]
   shippingDocument[]
           functions[]
```

I have a string array of functions in input paramaters (myFunctions).
Basically I want to achieve this mongo shell command with the C# API with aggregation pipeline.

```
{$match:{"functions":{$in:myFunctions,$not: {"$elemMatch":{"$nin":myFunctions}}}}}
```

=> If a find a single element not in the input array it's KO.

I need to do the same thing with the shippingDocument array but it is perfectly fine with the $project.

```
var db = client.GetDatabase("ecom");
var collection = db.GetCollection<Shipment>("shipment");

var query = collection.Aggregate()
.Match(
    Builders<Shipment>.Filter.Eq(x => x.reference, "XXX") &
    (/*{$match:{"functions":{$in:myFunctions,$not: {"$elemMatch":{"$nin":myFunctions}}}}}*/) 
   )
.Project(s => 
    new
    {
        Reference = s.reference,
        Documents = s.shippingDocuments.Where(d => d.functions.All(ro => myFunctions.Contains(ro)))
    }
);
```

If a try to add the match,

```
Builders<Shipment>.Filter.Where(x => x.functions.All(f => myFunctions.Contains(f)))
```

I have an exception,

```
Unsupported filter: All({document}{functions}.Where(Contains(value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String])))).
```

Any ideas to achieve this ?

Comment: So is there something wrong with simply specifying the `$match` stage from a BSON document definition? Particularly considering the expression should be much more brief than trying to apply builders to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I can't test it but can you write this:
Builders<Shipment>.Filter.Where(x => !x.functions.Except(myfunctions).Any())

source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another

Comment: It is perfectly fine in pure Linq but against MongoDB I get : Unsupported filter: Any({document}{functions}.Except(value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]))).

Comment: @Neil, actually if I apply a filter with a BsonDocument as :  BsonDocument.Parse($"{{'functions':{{$in:{myFunctions},$not: {{'$elemMatch':{{'$nin':{myFunctions}}}}}}}}}"); it works. But for developpers of my team, it would be quite easier to work with a "C#/Linq" approach.