# How to create multiply WHERE (and compare) with LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I have this request, and it works well. The main point of question is part `where filterIds.Contains(tags.UserTagId)`. It looks for all tags with **OR** kind.So if I have **filterIds** with 1,2,3 value it selects contact that have any of this tag.

```
 var result = (from conts in _context.Contacts
            where conts.CreatorUserId == _userManager.GetUserId(this.User) &&
                  (from tags in _context.ContactTags
                      where filterIds.Contains(tags.UserTagId)
                      select tags.ContactId).Contains(conts.ID)
            select new
            {
                conts.ID,  conts.Name, });
```

I need to find all ContactId with **AND** kind. So if contact contains Ids 1, and 2 and 3 - so give it to me.It's like find all contacts that have ALL of this tags.

```
 from tags in _context.ContactTags
            where filterIds[0] == tags.UserTagId 
and filterIds[1] == tags.UserTagId 
and filterIds[n] == tags.UserTagId
            select ...
```

or even

```
 (from tags in _context.ContactTags
                where filterIds[0] == tags.UserTagId 

                select ...) where filterIds[1] == tags.UserTagId ...
```

How to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another

Comment: Use two ampersands (not work and).

Comment: Except - makes separate request for every contact =(

Comment: I know about and - its just a sample =)

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution with Count =) (modified to Framwork LINQ)

```
 var result = _context.Contacts.Where(conts => conts.CreatorUserId == _userManager.GetUserId(this.User)
                              && conts.Tags.Where(t => filterIds.Contains(t.UserTagId)).Count() == filterIds.Count)
                .Select(conts=> new...
```