# Most optimal/performant way to filter out duplicate and containing lists

Tags: c#, algorithm, list

I have a large list of lists that contain ids.  What is the best way to filter out the duplicates and lists that are a subset of another list?  The problem that I have is that my algorithm increases almost exponentially in time as the size of my list with lists doubles.

I have tried multiple variations off the ContainsCombinatie including:

- Using a hashset
- Using a SortedList
- !t2.Except(t1).Any() as suggested in [Check whether an array is a subset of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another)

Below is a unit test with timer for you to try out.

```
    public class PerformanceTestThis
    {
        [Test]
        public void PerformanceTest2()
        {
            var allValues = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
            {
                allValues.Add(i);
            }

            var combinaties = new List<List<int>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                combinaties.Add(GenerateCombinatie(allValues));
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Generated {combinaties.Count} combinaties");

            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var result = new CollectionFilter().FilterDoubles(combinaties);
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Filtered down to {result.Count} combinaties");

            Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        private List<int> GenerateCombinatie(List<int> allVerstrekkingen)
        {
            var combinatie = new List<int>();
            var verstrekkingen = allVerstrekkingen.ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < Generator.GetRandomNumber(1000); i++)
            {
                var verstrekking = verstrekkingen[Generator.GetRandomNumber(verstrekkingen.Count)];
                combinatie.Add(verstrekking);
                verstrekkingen.Remove(verstrekking);
            }

            return combinatie.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class CollectionFilter
    {
        public List<List<int>> FilterDoubles(List<List<int>> combinaties)
        {
            var withoutDoubles = new List<List<int>>();
            foreach (var current in combinaties.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count))
            {
                if (!withoutDoubles.Any(list => ContainsCombinatie(list, current)))
                {
                    withoutDoubles.Add(current);
                }
            }

            return withoutDoubles;
        }

        private bool ContainsCombinatie(List<int> list1, List<int> list2)
        {
            return list2.All(list1.Contains);
        }
    }
```

Comment: By "doubles" do you mean *duplicates*?

Comment: Doubles I mean either a duplicate or a subset of another list.  As I said in "What is the best way to filter out the doubles and lists that are a subset of another list?"

Comment: It is confusing because `double` is a data type in C#.

Comment: Ok my applogies, I'll edit the question.

Comment: var distinctItems = items.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(y => y.First()); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose the following approach:

- Make a "collision" table

This table collects all concerned lists in front of each value.
Once done, some values has only one entry, others has many.

- Intersect the previous entries

For each list, calculate the intersection of the previous table entries (for the values in the list).
If the intersection has one element (the list itself), so it is not a double.

```
   public class CollectionFilter2
    {
        public List<List<int>> FilterDoubles( List<List<int>> combinaties )
        {
            // First part: collects collisions for each value in the list
            // This is done using a dictionary that holds all concerned lists in front of each value
            var hitDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<List<int>>>();
            foreach ( var comb in combinaties.Where( c => c.Count > 0 ) )
            {
                foreach ( var value in comb )
                {
                    if ( hitDictionary.TryGetValue( value, out var list ) == false )
                    {
                        list = new List<List<int>>();
                        hitDictionary[value] = list;
                    }

                    list.Add( comb );
                }
            }

            var result = new List<List<int>>();

            // Second part: search for lists for which one value has no collision
            foreach ( var comb in combinaties.Where( c => c.Count > 0 ) )
            {
                var count = comb.Count;

                // Initialize the intersection
                var inter = hitDictionary[comb[0]];

                // Makes the intersection for each value (or quit if the intersection is one list)
                for ( var i = 1 ; i < count && inter.Count > 1 ; i++ )
                    inter = inter.Intersect( hitDictionary[comb[i]] ).ToList();

                // If only one intersection, this is a result
                if ( inter.Count == 1 )
                    result.Add( comb );
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

For information, on my PC, the previous algorithm is around 8 seconds, this one is around 0.7 seconds (with the same counts given in the question).

**Edit:**

Considering linq "Intersect" [implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs), here is an optimized version base on the same principles:

```
public class CollectionFilter4
{
    class Temp
    {
        public List<int> Combinaty; // Original list
        public List<int> Values; // Distinct values
    }

    public List<List<int>> FilterDoubles( List<List<int>> combinaties )
    {
        // Generate distinct values
        var temps = combinaties.Where( c => c.Count > 0 ).Select( c => new Temp() { Combinaty = c, Values = c.Distinct().ToList() } ).ToList();

        // Collision dictionary (same as previous code)
        var hitDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<Temp>>();
        foreach ( var temp in temps )
        {
            foreach ( var value in temp.Values )
            {
                if ( hitDictionary.TryGetValue( value, out var list ) == false )
                {
                    list = new List<Temp>();
                    hitDictionary[value] = list;
                }

                list.Add( temp );
            }
        }

        // Ascending sort on collision count (this has an impact on the intersection later, as we want to keep the shortest anyway)
        temps.ForEach( t => t.Values.Sort( ( a, b ) => hitDictionary[a].Count.CompareTo( hitDictionary[b].Count ) ) );

        var result = new List<Temp>();

        foreach ( var temp in temps )
        {
            var values = temp.Values;
            var count = values.Count;

            var inter = new HashSet<Temp>(); // Create a hashset from the first value
            foreach ( var t in hitDictionary[values[0]] ) inter.Add( t );

            for ( var i = 1 ; i < count && inter.Count > 1 ; i++ )
            {
                // Rewritten intersection
                inter = Intersect( hitDictionary[values[i]], inter );
            }

            if ( inter.Count == 1 )
                result.Add( temp );
        }

        return result.Select( r => r.Combinaty ).ToList();
    }

    // Same as original linq code except but optimized for this case
    static HashSet<TSource> Intersect<TSource>( IEnumerable<TSource> first, HashSet<TSource> second )
    {
        var result = new HashSet<TSource>();

        foreach ( TSource element in first )
            if ( second.Remove( element ) ) result.Add( element );

        return result;
    }
}
```

Here is the linq (more generic) implementation, for information:

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> IntersectIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
        {
            Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
            foreach (TSource element in second) set.Add(element);
            foreach (TSource element in first)
                if (set.Remove(element)) yield return element;
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, I'm going to try it out with some variations in list size.

Comment: I've done it, after the answer... tried 100k instead of 10k. Still better (93s vs. 1400s). But I think this is dependent of the domains (lists count, lists sizes, lists possible values). There is also a problem I've think about after writing the answer: exact duplicates are not part of the result. So this is to improve...

Comment: Hey Lemon, I have to say it's unique and a very out of the box solutions.  Much better than my original algorithm.  If no one else comes up with a better answer within the next couple of days I'll accept this answer.  Thanks a lot for the effort.