# How to compare two arrays of chars and see location?

Tags: c#, arrays, char, comparison

Example: first sequence (A,B,C,D)
second sequence (X,A,Z,A,B,C,D,E,A)

The first sequence is contained in the second sequence from position 4 because the letters A, B, C, D appear in exactly the same order as the first sequence

```
char[] firstSequence = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
char[] secondSequence = new char[] {'X','A','Z','A','B','C','D','E','A'}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide your attempt so we can push you in the right direction.

Comment: try joining both (each join it to become string) sequences then checking if the other contains the first

Comment: 1. Does (A, B, C, D) contain itself `(A, B, C, D)`? 2. Does `(A, X, B, C, D)` contain `(A, B, C, D)`?

Comment: what do you mean by "all instances"? do you need to count how many are there? the way you have formulated your question, it seems that you need to extract several strings that are already the same. also- please show what you have tried already, so that we can see what the problem is

Comment: elaborate more your question. so you need code to search a pattern on a string ?

Comment: you mean just a subset check or they have to be "ordered"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another

Answer (score 4):

Note; at the time this answer was written it wasn't clear that sequences under discussion were arrays of char. This answer gives a more general advice for collections of strings or complex types. For arrays of char a specific optimisation of not having a string.Join separator or using the string constructor that takes a char array, would be an option; other answers mention this so I won't repeat it here

---

Not really sure how you're storing your sequences but hopefully they're enumerable in which case:

```
string.Join(",", haystackCollection).Contains(string.Join(",", needleCollection));
```

I used comma as a separator but you should use a character that never occurs in the actual collections

More full example:

```
var haystackCollection = "XAZABCDEA".ToCharArray();
var needleCollection = "ABCD".ToCharArray();

bool result = string.Join(",", haystackCollection).Contains(string.Join(",", needleCollection));
```

This is only reliable if your collections are strings of identical length . It becomes unreliable if the haystack could contain strings of varying length because a haystack of `{"AB","AC"}` doesn't contain a needle of `{"B","A"}` but this method would report that it does.

You could fudge it to be better by putting separators at the start and end of each string join op:

```
string s = ",";
(s+string.Join(s, haystackCollection)+s).Contains(s+string.Join(",", needleCollection)+s);
```

But it might be better at this point to switch method entirely. Also if you want to know the index it occurs at it's a bit trickier using this string join method because you'd have to use IndexOf and then repeatedly subtract the lengths of each element plus the separator to get back to the index. You might be better off using loops instead:

```
int idx = 0;
while(idx < haystack.Length){
  if(haystack[idx] == needle[0]){
    int i = 1;
    while(haystack[idx+i] == needle[i] && i<needle.Length)
      i++;
    if(i == needle.Length)
      return idx; // you found the start of the needle
  }
  idx++;
}
```

In this latter method we start looking through the haystack trying to find the first element of the needle. If we find it, we start a loop that checks the rest of the needle. That loop only keeps gong while it finds needle entries in the haystack. If the loop stops early then the index variable `i` won't increment all the way up to the length of the needle array so we can conclude that if the variable `i` is indeed equal to the the Length of the needle, the needle was found at the position `idx` in the haystack

For this method to work out you really need your collections to be indexable by Integer rather than just enumerable, unless you want to get more convoluted. Remember that if you're using List instead of Array then it's Count rather than Length

Comment: it will work even if the separator was contained in the actual collections

Comment: Or string.Join("", haystackCollection).IndexOf(string.Join("", needleCollection))

Comment: @MohammadAli I was thinking not to use a char from the collections just in case things are more complex than presented here, for example a haystack of `AA,AA` and a needle of `A,A` - if you use A as a separator it will misreport that the haystack contains the needle

Comment: @Tohm IndexOf would need some additional manipulation to remove the lengths of all the separators. If the haystack contains variable length strings that would cause further complications

Answer (score 2):

Convert your firstSequence and secondSequence into string and then use `.Contains()`.

```
//Inputs
char[] firstSequence = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
char[] secondSequence = new char[] {'X','A','Z','A','B','C','D','E','A'}

//Convert char array to string
string firstString = new string(firstSequence);
string secondString = new string(secondSequence);

//Use .Contains() to check string availability
bool isExist = secondString.Contains(firstString);

//Print message on console
Console.WriteLine(isExist ? "Sequence Exist" : "Sequence Not Exist");

//This will give you staring index of first string in second string i.e 3
//Next four will be your indexes that are 3, 4, 5, 6
if(isExist)
   {
       int startIndex = secondString.IndexOf(firstString);
       Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(startIndex , firstString.Length)));
   }
```

Result:

```
Sequence Exist
3, 4, 5, 6
```

[.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j6s57V)

Comment: If you can put in the answer.
I have no preference, can be looped or without loop.

Comment: @Hora, I updated my answer with fiddle kindly check

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear about your question , but if you mean that you want to find position of a string in another string you can use this :

```
  char[] firstSequence = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
  char[] secondSequence = new char[] {'X','A','Z','A','B','C','D','E','A'}
  var firstString = new string(firstSequence);
  var secondString = new string(secondSequence);
  var positionIndex = secondString.IndexOf(fisrtString);
```

Comment: Yes I want. But I want to find the position of the vector.. In the example it would be 3,4,5,6

Comment: hi Welcome to stackoverflow. I believe you are trying to find index of A,B,C,D in second string i.e. 'X','A','Z','A','B','C','D','E','A'. If this is the case then I updated your answer. If this is not the case then let me know I will revote it to previous state

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to test that `firstSequence` items appear somewhere within `secondSequence` in the same order that in `firstSequence`, e.g.

```
 {A, X, A, B, P, Q, D, A, C, D}
        ^  ^              ^  ^  
        A  B              C  D
```

You can try *Linq* `Aggregate`: having item `a` and `index` within `firstSequence` we want to match, we can compute `index` we want to match with next item in `secondSequence`

**Code:**

```
using System.Linq;

... 

bool contains = secondSequence.Aggregate(0, 
   (index, a) => (index >= firstSequence.Length) || (firstSequence[index] != a)
     ? index                               // match completed or nothing to macth 
     : index + 1) >= firstSequence.Length; // match next item
```

Same idea, but different `Aggregate` if all `firstSequence` must appear without interuptions:

```
 {A, X, A, B, C, D, P, Q}
        ^  ^  ^  ^  
        A  B  C  D
```

**Code:**

```
using System.Linq;

... 

bool contains = secondSequence
  .Aggregate(0, (index, a) =>
       index >= firstSequence.Length ? index // match found, do nothing
     : firstSequence[index] == a ? index + 1 // can we match next item?
     : firstSequence[0] == a ? 1             // restart and match the 1st item
     : 0)                                    // restart
    >= firstSequence.Length;                 // Have we match all items?
```

Comment: This post would hugely benefit from some surrounding explanation.  As it stands it's effectively a code only answer because though it contains non code blocks it's effectively "here's a bunch of LINQ. It works"