# cannot convert nullable long to not nullable long in c# linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Class1
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<long?> degreeIds { get; set; }
    public long schoolId { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public List<long> degreeIds { get; set; }
}

public class Class3
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public long schoolId { get; set; }
}
```

I got the data from some where and I am looping with some data and assigning it not nullable one. cannot convert long? to long

Comment: var filteredData = class1.
                    .Where(x => x.schoolId == class3.schoolId &&
                                class2.degreeIds.Contains(x.degreeIds)).ToList();

Comment: "*I got the data from some where and I am looping with some data and assigning it not nullable one*" -- show this code, please

Comment: var filteredData = class1.
                    .Where(x => x.schoolId == class3.schoolId &&
                                class2.degreeIds.Contains(x.degreeIds)).ToList(); @canton7 while executing this type of linq it is getting issue

Comment: @bmdprasad Please don't add further information in the comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: @bmdprasad: Well, that makes sense.  You can't convert a `long?` to a `long` because the former supports values which the latter does not.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: i just want to filter the values which contains class1.degreeids(x.degreeids) in calss2.degreeids. but here class2 degree ids are not nullable and class1.degreeids are nullable

Comment: You can't do `.Contains(list)`. In your case, only `.Contains(long)` would work. Do you want to find out if *all* of the `x.degreeIds` exist in `class2.degreeIds` or if *any* of them exists?

Comment: @Longoon12000 I want all of the x.degreeids

Answer (score 4):

I would check if the value is null, and ignore those where relevant.

```
List<long> list = degreeIds.Where(p => p.HasValue).Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: i just want to filter the values which contains class1.degreeids(x.degreeids) in calss2.degreeids. but here class2 degree ids are not nullable and class1.degreeids are nullable

Comment: Wouldn't this still be an issue because youre still storing long? Objects into a list of Long without a cast? -- or can it go one way but not the other?

Comment: @bmdprasad I do not get that from your question - Care to edit your posted question with the additional requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that you want to check if Class1 degreeIds contains **all** of the Class2 degreeIds, check out this: [Check whether an array is a subset of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another)

I'm not sure on which object you're doing this `.Where` on but I assume it's a `List<Class1>` since `x` seems to be of type Class1. I'll call it `class1List` in this code.

Using this method you would then do:

```
var filteredData = class1List.Where(x =>
    x.schoolId == class3.schoolId &&
    !class2.degreeIds.Except(x.degreeIds
        .Where(deg => deg.HasValue)
        .Select(deg => deg.Value))
        .Any()).ToList();
```

This would select all `long?` that have a value (`.HasValue`) and then select the actual `long` value (`.Value`), remove all these values from the `class2.degreesIds` and check if there are any elements left. If there are none it means that `class2.degreesIds` had no values in it that didn't exist in `x.degreeIds`.